# How to Manipulate Variable Value inside a Function When The Variable was Declared Outside the Function?

Tags: python

I would like to increase the value of variable `count` by 1, but only when the function `printcount` is called in the CODE below.

```
global count
count = 0

def PrintCount():
    count += 1
    print count

PrintCount()
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cross\Desktop\Code.py", line 8, in <module>
    PrintCount()
  File "C:\Users\Cross\Desktop\Code.py", line 5, in PrintCount
    count += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

I would like to know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `global` keyword  **inside the function** to access (especially modify) the global variable `count`:

```
def PrintCount():
    global count # <----
    count += 1
    print count
```

Declaring global outside the function has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

In python, you can read the global variables but you cannot change them without `global` keyword.

```
def PrintCount():
    global count
    count += 1
    print count
```

But the best way to do this would be to pass the `count` as a parameter to the function, do processing, return the value like this. Try to avoid `global` as much as possible.

```
def increment(count):
    print count + 1
    return count + 1
count = increment(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0

def PrintCount():
    global count
    count += 1
    print count

Print()
```